# Cloning an object does not update bound values in UI - WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

I've searched through many questions but I can only find mentions of 'observable' collections which isn't applicable to my situation.

I have a basic WPF app, an Address class and a simple form which contains 'delivery address' and 'billing address' along with a checkbox to copy the del address to billing address (which I do by cloning the Address object). I can see the billing address properties updated to that as entered for the delivery address, but this values are not updated back to the UI. I'm sure there is a better way to accomplish this. So far I ahve

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApp1.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApp1"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
<Grid>
    <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
    <TextBox Text="{Binding Path=DelAddress.Line1, Mode=TwoWay}"></TextBox>
        <TextBox Text="{Binding Path=DelAddress.Line2, Mode=TwoWay}"></TextBox>
        <TextBox Text="{Binding Path=DelAddress.Line3, Mode=TwoWay}"></TextBox>

    <CheckBox Checked="CopyDelAddress"> Same as Delivery</CheckBox>
        <TextBox Text="{Binding Path=BillAddress.Line1, Mode=TwoWay}"></TextBox>
        <TextBox Text="{Binding Path=BillAddress.Line2, Mode=TwoWay}"></TextBox>
        <TextBox Text="{Binding Path=BillAddress.Line3, Mode=TwoWay}"></TextBox>
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

```
namespace WpfApp1 {
/// <summary>
/// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
/// </summary>
public partial class MainWindow : Window {

    public class Address {
        public string Line1 { get; set; }
        public string Line2 { get; set; }
        public string Line3 { get; set; }
        public Address Clone() {
            return (Address)this.MemberwiseClone();
        }
    }
    public Address DelAddress { get; set; }
    public Address BillAddress { get; set; }
    public MainWindow() {
        InitializeComponent();

        BillAddress = new Address();
        DelAddress = new Address();

        DataContext = this;
    }

    private void CopyDelAddress(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) {
        BillAddress = DelAddress.Clone();
    // Values are copied to BillAddress but don't appear in the UI
    }
}
}
```

Comment: You don't fire a change notification event when the BillAddress property changes. Either implement INotifyPropertyChanged or make BillAddress a dependency property.

Comment: You will have to set your classes to inherit INotifyPropertyChanged, which will tell the UI that a property of an object has changed. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/data/how-to-implement-property-change-notification

Comment: You are missing some stuff required to make data-binding work.  I suggest googling data-binding and find a simple example that you can modify.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How do you expect the UI to know that you changed the value of the property? You never told it.

You should move `BillAddress` and `DelAddress` to a viewmodel class that [implements INotifyPropertyChanged](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) and make that your DataContext.

This code is C#7. If you're using an earlier version, let me know and I'll fix it to be compatible with your compiler.

MainWindow.xaml.cs

```
public MainWindow() {
    InitializeComponent();

    DataContext = new MainViewModel();
}

public MainViewModel ViewModel => (MainViewModel)DataContext;


private void CopyDelAddress(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) {
    ViewModel.BillAddress = ViewModel.DelAddress.Clone();

    //  Values ARE NOT copied to BillAddress. A clone of DelAddress 
    //  is assigned to BillAddress.
}
```

ViewModels.cs

```
public class MainViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    public MainViewModel()
    {
        BillAddress = new Address();
        DelAddress = new Address();
    }

    private Address _billAddress = null;
    public Address BillAddress
    {
        get { return _billAddress; }
        set
        {
            if (value != _billAddress)
            {
                _billAddress = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }
    }

    private Address _delAddress = null;
    public Address DelAddress
    {
        get { return _delAddress; }
        set
        {
            if (value != _delAddress)
            {
                _delAddress = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }
    }
}

public class ViewModelBase : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    #region INotifyPropertyChanged
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([System.Runtime.CompilerServices.CallerMemberName] string propName = null) =>
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propName));
    #endregion INotifyPropertyChanged
}
```

Comment: Thanks for point me in the right direction, switching to a view model with the above code was exactly what I was looking for. Shout out to the down voters!